# How to select a select box element using java script when select box using foreach in php

Tags: javascript, php

i have select box element using foreach in php :

```
    <select class="form-control" id="sopir" name="sopir">
          <?php
            foreach($array_sopir as $nik=>$nama){
                echo '<option value="'.$nik.'">'.$nama.'</option>';
            }
          ?>
   </select>
```

I have tried to use this `document.getElementById('sopir').value = valueToSelect;` but it does not work.
how can i to select value with javascript ?

Comment: you'll need to hook it into the onchange event, then use `sopir` in your id

Comment: @Ghost if i do not use 'foreach' this works fine. but this does not work when I use foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

`document.getElementById(sopir).value = valueToSelect;`

To

`document.getElementById('sopir').value = valueToSelect;`

Missing single/double quotes around the `sopir` indicates that `sopir` is a variable and not actual element id.

Provided `valueToSelect` has a value that matches at least one option from drop down.

Comment: sorry i made the writing wrong here. but I've been like you said in my script

Comment: @satewedos, can you please explain what problem you are facing.

Comment: I've solved my problem, it turns out my valueToSelect does not have a value that matches the dropdown. thanks for your help